# mysql and php connection

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

friends i'm a beginner to create a database i'm using xampp for creating the                                   database
     I have added my data's with mysql in xampp but i don't know to connect my mysql with  php (for web page)

```
<html>
<body>
<marquee behavior="alternate">welcome</marquee>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
$username = "root";
$password = "root123";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
?>
<?php
$selected = mysql_select_db("missensencemuttation",$dbhandle) 
or die("Could not select missensencemuttation");
?>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `primary_data` LIMIT 0, 30");
($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)); 
{
echo "disease_name:".$row{'disease_name'}." gene_name:".$row{'gene_name'};
}
?>enter code here
<?php
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

this what i did for connecting my database with php

but in the result i can see only my first row of my table 
I have 10 rows in it. but when I used to connect them I can see only my first row. in my php

### can any one help me to connect all my data's in php?

```
<html>
<body>
<marquee behavior="alternate">welcome to the database</marquee>
<table border="3" align="center">
<tr><th>disase_name</th><th>gene_name</th></tr>      
<?php 
        $username = "root";
        $password = "2991";
        $hostname = "localhost"; 
        $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to   connect to MySQL");
        echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
        $selected = mysql_select_db("disease",$dbhandle) or die("Could not select  disease");
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `primary_data` LIMIT 0, 30");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr><td>".$row['disease_name']."</td><td>".$row['gene_name']."</td>   </tr>";
        }
        mysql_close($dbhandle);
    ?>
    </table>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

### the answer i expected friends comes with this code

Comment: You only fetch one row and display it in your code. You need a loop, which is covered by any PHP tutorial.

Comment: do note that `mysql_connect` and similar functions is deprecated for new versions of PHP. If this is a new project, try [mysqli_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) for better future proofing.

Comment: Another note its best not to post details like 'username', 'password' & 'hostname'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a while loop to loop through all results which have been returned.
Every mysql_fetch_array(), the MySQL result jumps to the next record.

You can use the following code to loop through all lines

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "disease_name:".$row['disease_name']." gene_name:".$row['gene_name'];
}
```

Your complete code would look like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <marquee behavior="alternate">welcome</marquee>
        <?php 
            $username = "root";
            $password = "root123";
            $hostname = "localhost"; 
            $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
            echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

            $selected = mysql_select_db("missensencemuttation",$dbhandle) or die("Could not select missensencemuttation");
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `primary_data` LIMIT 0, 30");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "disease_name:".$row['disease_name']." gene_name:".$row['gene_name'];
            }
            mysql_close($dbhandle);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

*Thanks to Edwin Alex for the comment about the semicolon*

Comment: nope i cant get my results

Comment: You should remove semi colon here while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result));

Comment: Are you sure you have data in your `primary_data` table? In PHP, you can check this by using "mysql_affected_rows($result)", which will return the result row count (integer)

Comment: Yep, Edwin is right, I will edit it

Comment: ya i'm having data's in my primary_data table

Comment: Connected to MySQL
Could not select missensencemuttation this what php said when i am running my program

Comment: thanks yaar its working my mistake in $selected = mysql_select_db("missensencemuttation",$dbhandle) its missence_muttation.. sorry ya thanks for the help

Comment: @EdwinAlex i need my results in a form of table.. how can i do that.

Comment: no problem edwin i done it using <th><tr><td> thanks u very much for ur help friends

Answer (score 0):

User `"["` here.

```
echo "disease_name:".$row['disease_name']." gene_name:".$row['gene_name'];
```

Also you should loop it and display.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
 echo "disease_name:".$row['disease_name']." gene_name:".$row['gene_name'];
}
```

Comment: nope i cant get my results its showing error

Comment: @Mano Better run the query in any of the mysql editor and check how many records it returns?

Comment: ya thanks @Edwin i got my answers thank u